# using Python to copy .npz files from a folder and its subfolders, all to some other single folder

Tags: glob, subdirectory, shutil

The following code copies all **.npz** files in folder **C:/Users/toTEST** into folder **C:/Users/archive**

```
import glob
import shutil
dest_dir = "C:/Users/archive"
for file in glob.glob(r'C:/Users/toTEST/*.npz'):
    print(file)
    shutil.copy(file, dest_dir)
```

But the **toTEST** folder has several subfolders, and I would also like to move their **.npz** files into the **archive** folder as well.   How can this be efficiently achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do the trick:

```
import shutil
import glob

path = 'C:/Users/toTEST/**/'
dest = 'C:/Users/archive/'
pattern = '*.npz'

selectfiles = glob.glob(path + pattern, recursive=True)

for file in selectfiles:
    shutil.copy2(file, dest)
```